# Configure run python button to run in current VSCode terminal (instead of opening a new one)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, command-line-interface

I've been looking everywhere online but haven't found the solution to this yet.

I use VSCode's Git Bash terminal for everything in my workflow. With Python, by default there's a run and debug button
[Button looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM1Mp.png)

When you click this button it opens a new terminal to run the Python script instead of using the already active terminal. My terminals take forever to load which is a separate issue but typically it's 30-45 seconds for a new terminal to open.

In the newly opened console it runs the Python with the command
`python -u "path to Python file"`

In git bash I can simply type python "name of file" as long as I'm in the correct cd.

Is there a way to modify how this button works so that it will just run in the current Bash terminal instead of opening a new terminal to run in? OR is there something I can change to make my terminals load faster?

I've tried modifying settings and Googling answers but haven't found an ideal solution yet for what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

> In the newly opened console it runs the Python with the command `python -u "path to Python file`

Then you are using the *Code Runner* extension to execute scripts, please use the official extension **Python** to execute scripts (***Run Python File***), this button remembers your last selection.

[image]

Comment: That still seems to open a new Python terminal to run the file instead of running in the already opened bash terminal.

Comment: It will open a new python terminal the first time you click it, but will not open a new terminal after that.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand that's how it works, I was wondering if there's a way around it opening that new terminal altogether. Seems strange to me. I think I prefer to just run python {path} in the bash console.

Comment: You can set the default terminal type to bash. note that the python displayed on the terminal is just the name of this terminal, it is not a terminal type. If you set the default terminal type, then the new terminal it opens is bash.